# Analyzing Opamp circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt

I was asked to analyze this Op-amp circuit and I need a little bit of advice about it. I have presented my analysis about the circuit, kindly correct me wherever I am going wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOBehR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. If a positive voltage is applied at Vref then the negetive terminal should also necessarily have its voltage at the same.
2. Hence a current will try to flow through the 100 ohm resistor into the ground, but will be unable to do so, since there is no circuit path. What I don't understand is what will happen in this case, will there be a current flowing through the amp feedback short path?
3. If the reference voltage is negetive, a current may flow through the emitter, but what will be the voltage at the base? And even if a current flows through the emitter, will the reverse biased LED through the collector allow this.

Hence, I think the circuit is wrong, please give me your suggestions...

P.S. The diode D1 is a laser Diode, I don't know what that implies. Is it different from an LED diode?

Comment: I'm assuming the transistor should be NPN instead of reversed PNP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this with falstad.com/circuit and clearly see what happens
I've [build it already for you](http://falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0Aa+208+272+288+272+0+15.0+-15.0+1000000.0%0A172+208+288+160+288+0+6+8.399999999999999+10.0+-10.0+0.0+0.5+Vref%0At+288+272+352+272+1+-1+1.7763568394002505E-15+15.000839985+100.0%0Ar+352+336+352+384+0+100.0%0Ag+352+384+352+416+0%0A162+352+176+352+256+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0AR+352+112+352+64+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Aw+320+288+320+224+0%0Aw+320+224+208+224+0%0Aw+208+224+208+256+0%0Aw+352+288+352+336+0%0Aw+352+336+320+336+0%0Aw+320+336+320+288+0%0Ar+352+112+352+176+0+100.0%0A) just play with the slider for Vref and see what happens.

When Vref = -1V then there has to be -1V over (-) of the opamp
to get this the opamp's output has to be negative so that a basis current can flow this current  comes from the emitter the colector current will be higher and the led will turn on

When Vref = +1V then Vemmitor should be 1V but this can never be achieved so the opamp's output will be  (+1V-(0A))* ampfactor => opamps max saturation voltage
So the transistor basis is high and there won't be any current flowing through the led

you can see it like this, in this particular circuit
[image]

Comment: Okay, but what I don't understand is that why is the transistor drawing current inwards at the collector. Shouldn't the current direction be outward at the collector of a pnp. Or else how would the relationship Ib+Ic=Ie stand?

Comment: it's more something like this in that circuit
http://www.ibiblio.org/tkan/audio/bjt2.png